# I have a 5 bit decrementer. Using control i/p R, use the decrementer and 2-i/p XOR gates to obtain incrementer when R=0 and a decrementer when R = 1

Tags: digital-logic, computer-architecture, algorithm

The progress I made is that I used a XOR gate with the complement of R, to be fed as input to each of the first 4 inputs of the decrementer. It doesn't seem to work for all input combinations.
 I would appreciate some suggestions on modification, as this doesn't lead to correct outputs. 
[image]
I tried to find out the logical expressions of the incrementer and decrementer individually to link them together using the control input R. Please have a look at the attached figure.

Kindly refer to the attached figure. The expressions that the output needs to assume in each case (R=0 and R=1) have been derived already by me. I can't find a way to link them together.

Comment: I tried to upload an image, but it says that the image size is too big. And yeah, I'm new in this portal.

Comment: I use Irfanview to shrink image OR file sizes with compression

Comment: I uploaded the image now. Used some online compression tools. Have a look, if you have time.

Comment: We can guess but we need a bit more of a definition of the block that you have called a 5 bit decrementer.

Comment: If the input is X, the output of the decrementer is X-1. That's about it. The internal design can't be modified in this question.

Answer (score -1):

A down counter just inverts all the ouputs.

Comment: It doesn't do that always. Suppose you have 11101 as input. The output of the downcounter will be 11100. So, all inputs aren't inverted.

Comment: I said invert the outputs. With a Reset or parallel load of 00000 the output will be 11111 and count down.

Comment: How'll that work?

Comment: Could you elaborate? 
Suppose the input is 11001. For R=0, we want output = 11010 and for R=1, we want 11000. That's the basic thing. I don't see the result coming from any simple inversion.

Comment: You don't have provision for that. You can't use any additional components to reset it. All you have is the decrementer and any number of XOR gates.

Comment: a row of XOR's on both inputs and outputs will convert it from down counter to an up counter but not a bidirectional up/down counter.

Comment: So, how do I do it? That is, have an up/down counter depending on the control input R?

Comment: My expressions are correct, right? So, how do I link the down and up counter operations via the control input?

Comment: you do not have an up counter in your photo. you dont even have a load pulse for input register or even a clock. and we dont call them incrementers. We call them counters. An up/down needs an adder.

Comment: like this http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4516b-mil.pdf

Comment: I get that. But a counter keeps decrementing/incrementing the outut at each clock pulse. This one's a combinational circuit. It just adds 1 to the input in case of an incrementer and subtracts 1 in case of a decrementer, and just stops there. There surely exists terms like incrementers and decrementers. I myself learnt it in my course. The question doesn't call for the sequential type counter. My use of the word counter in the last comment was a mistake. I meant to imply the combinational circuit only, as specified by the question.